# Brownian motions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and Cauchy distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I can't  solve  this problem

Let $Z_t=(X_t,Y_t)$ a brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it starts in (0,1). Let $T=\inf\{t\geq 0: Y_t=0\}$. Show that $X_T$ has Cauchy distribution.

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082069/cauchy-density-function-for-brownian-motion

Comment: The problem is that in my case a=0 and in that case a>0 and if a will be zero then everything there will be zero right?

Comment: I think that in your case, $a=1$ because you're looking for the first time a Brownian motion started at $1$ reaches $0$. Using symmetry, this is equivalent to the first time that a Brownian motion started at $0$ reaches $1$. Notice that with $a=1$ you find exactly a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Yes I'm going to do that. Thanks you